# Empty data cell validation

Tags: javascript, validation, google-sheets, google-docs-api

How can I add validation on cell, that checks if the cell is not empty after creating new data record? Something like mandatory fields.

Comment: In a Google Docs spreadsheet? What should the result of the validation be? Change the formatting?

Comment: No, it should be warning (or prompt) that record was inserted without filled mandatory fields

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible (in the way I think you are requesting). From [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139705?hl=en):

> If data validation is applied to cells containing data, rules won't be applied until the data is modified.

That does not actually say "No, it is not possible" but I think can be inverted as, "No modification, no trigger for validation" - and I'm assuming your cells start off empty (though for blanks I think it does not actually make any difference).

I suggest considering alternatives, possibly conditional formatting of cells that are empty (there is specific provision for `Cell is empty`), a formula to count the number of blanks cells in a range that should be populated (since you mention records you might prefer a row to be flagged rather than each individual blank cell), or resorting to a script.

Comment: The issue is not that cells start off empty: even if they are pre-filled with compliant  values, the user will be able to blank them out. E.g., enter "abc" in cell A1 with validation rule "=LEN(A1)>2". Although a user won't be able to replace the value by "a" or "ab", they will be allowed to enter empty string there. Only data-containing cells are subject to data validation.