# make cells mandatory to fill in google sheets with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am new to programming. Is there a way of making a cell mandatory to be filled in google sheets or microsoft excel using javascript, where by a message pops up to remind users to fill in the cells.

Comment: Seems like there might be a solution here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129604/how-can-we-make-a-field-cell-value-mandatory-if-another-field-cell-have-spec

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995055/empty-data-cell-validation) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76414/is-there-a-way-to-force-someone-to-enter-a-non-empty-value-string-in-a-cell-in-g). Please let me know if it helps you.